# Youtube Channel Search script

Tags: python, api, parsing, youtube, youtube-api

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Installing the API key and creating an instance of the youtube object
api_key = "***"
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

# Channel search function
def search_channels(query, min_subscriber_count=0, published_after=None):
    # Defining request parameters
    query_params = {
        'q': query,
        'type': 'channel',
        'part': 'id,snippet',
        'maxResults': 10,
        'order': 'relevance'
    }
    # Adding filtering parameters
    if min_subscriber_count > 0:
        query_params['minSubscriberCount'] = min_subscriber_count

    if published_after is not None:
        query_params['publishedAfter'] = published_after
    # Request execution
    request = youtube.search().list(**query_params)
    response = request.execute()
    channels = []
    # Processing of results
    for item in response['items']:
        channel = {
            'id': item['id']['channelId'],
            'title': item['snippet']['title'],
            'description': item['snippet']['description'],
            'published_at': item['snippet']['publishedAt'],
            'thumbnail': item['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url'],
            'subscriber_count': 0
        }
        # Getting information about the number of subscribers
        statistics = youtube.channels().list(
            part='statistics',
            id=channel['id']
        ).execute()
        if statistics['items']:
            channel['subscriber_count'] = int(statistics['items'][0]['statistics']['subscriberCount'])
        channels.append(channel)
    return channels

# Example of using the function search_channels
six_months_ago = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=180)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
channels = search_channels('python', min_subscriber_count=50000, published_after=six_months_ago)
for channel in channels:
    print(f"{channel['title']} ({channel['subscriber_count']} subscribers)")
```

Issues an oibc: File "C:\Users\Puzyrin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py " , line 1048, in the raise TypeError method("An unexpected argument of the keyword {}" was received.format(name)) TypeError: An unexpected argument of the minSubscriberCount keyword was received

Please help with the names in the API.

Answer (score 0):

`minSubscriberCount` isn't documented in [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint.

As far as I know there isn't any way to efficiently filter channels based on a given number of subscribers lower bound. The most efficient workaround consists in applying your filter criterion thanks to YouTube Data API v3 [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint with [`part=statistics`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#part) which can ingest up to 50 video ids per request.